# Every child of a RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox must have an ID in its parent data

Tags: flutter, error-handling

I am trying to replace flutter's red screen with my own screen( a loading screen). But the app crashes when it is triggered. Here is how I am replacing the screen

```
ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Loading"),
    ),
    body: Positioned(
      child:Loading()
    ),

  );
```

And the loading widget is

```
Container(
      child: Center(
         child: SpinKitFadingCube(
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 50.0,
          )
      ),
      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
    );
```

The stacktrace is

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4952 pos 16: 'child is! ParentDataElement<ParentData>': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/Hemant/AndroidStudioProjects/discountapp/lib/main.dart:10:58
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Every child of a RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox must have an ID in its parent data.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/Hemant/AndroidStudioProjects/discountapp/lib/main.dart:10:58
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
Every child of a RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox must have an ID in its parent data.

The following child has no ID: _RenderColoredBox#1154c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=null
...  constraints: MISSING
...  size: MISSING
...  behavior: opaque
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/Hemant/AndroidStudioProjects/discountapp/lib/main.dart:10:58
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:228:13)
#1      MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:234:10)
#2      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:401:14)
#3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1776:7)
#4      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#ea7eb relayoutBoundary=up6
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=646.8)
...  size: Size(392.7, 646.8)
RenderObject: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#ea7eb relayoutBoundary=up6
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=646.8)
  size: Size(392.7, 646.8)
...  child 1: _RenderColoredBox#1154c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=null
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    behavior: opaque
...    child: RenderPositionedBox#4cf2c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: <none>
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      alignment: center
...      textDirection: ltr
...      widthFactor: expand
...      heightFactor: expand
...      child: RenderPositionedBox#79ddb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        alignment: center
...        textDirection: ltr
...        widthFactor: expand
...        heightFactor: expand
...        child: RenderConstrainedBox#ba168 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...          additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=50.0, h=50.0)
...  child 2: RenderConstrainedBox#26ec0 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.appBar
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=56.0)
...    child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#95f4f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: <none>
...      constraints: MISSING
...      semantic boundary
...      size: MISSING
...      child: RenderAnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>#5aedc NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        child: RenderPhysicalModel#177a3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none>
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
...          elevation: 4.0
...          color: MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff2196f3))
...          shadowColor: MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff2196f3))
...          shape: BoxShape.rectangle
...          borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero
...  child 3: RenderStack#c7c1d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton
...    constraints: MISSING
...    size: MISSING
...    alignment: centerRight
...    textDirection: ltr
...    fit: loose
...    child 1: RenderTransform#9b142 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      size: MISSING
...      transform matrix: [0] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[1] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
...      origin: null
...      alignment: center
...      textDirection: ltr
...      transformHitTests: true
...      child: RenderTransform#9f5b2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...        parentData: <none>
...        constraints: MISSING
...        size: MISSING
...        transform matrix: [0] 0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[1] -0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
...        origin: null
...        alignment: center
...        textDirection: ltr
...        transformHitTests: true
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
W/libEGL  (22033): EGLNativeWindowType 0x7019d6f010 disconnect failed
```

I have tried replacing the loading screen with a simple Text Widget. Same Thing happens. I found out how to do this from another stackoverflow post. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 7):

Things you can try,

- Wrap the Positioned() Widget with a stack.
- Provide width and height constraints to Container

---

```
      Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(top:  10,child: Loading(.....))
        ],
      ),
```

Not sure why you need positioning Widget but, above is the way to go.

---

```
Container(
       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Center(
     child: SpinKitFadingCube(
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 50.0,
      )
  ),
  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
);
```

And this is how you should have it constrained(Example).

Comment: Sorry. It turns out it was my mistake and I had not written the code for the main class properly. Rookie error