# Every child of a RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox must have an ID in its parent data error when opening application

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a widget that has a sidebar and I have the following code

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Expanded(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            SafeArea(
                child: NavigationRail(
              selectedIndex: 0,
              onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
                print('Test');
              },
              destinations: [
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: Text("Home"),
                ),
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: Text("a"),
                ),
              ],
            )),
            SignUpPage(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I'm getting the error
`Every child of a RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox must have an ID in its parent data.` when opening the application in debug mode

Here's the code for SignUpPage, but not sure it's needed and it is a bit long: https://pastebin.com/j1knyKFw

---

Already looked at [the other stack overflow thread about this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068383/every-child-of-a-rendercustommultichildlayoutbox-must-have-an-id-in-its-parent-d) but it didn't help in my case

Tried debugging with BingGPT, but that didn't lead anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the sample code to begin with.

Firstly, look at the output of the below-mentioned source code: [View](https://i.ibb.co/D8D9N7T/Simulator-Screen-Shot-i-Phone-SE-3rd-generation-2023-09-04-at-13-07-24.png).

Now, copy & paste the below-mentioned source code into your `main.dart` file.

Source code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            NavigationRail(
              selectedIndex: currentIndex,
              labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
              destinations: const <NavigationRailDestination>[
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one),
                  label: Text("One"),
                ),
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two),
                  label: Text("Two"),
                ),
              ],
              onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
                currentIndex = index;
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
            const VerticalDivider(),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(currentIndex == 0 ? Icons.looks_one : Icons.looks_two),
                  Text(currentIndex == 0 ? "One" : "Two"),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I compared my code to yours and figured out that I needed to remove the expanded element. I also realized that I was also getting a Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget error, which I didn't notice somehow. Thanks!